Default Caching Behavior for Spring boot
Im adding a cache-controll header via
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                .header("Test", tag).header("Cache-Control","public")
                .body(Responses);

But in the response, the Cache-contorl header is duplicated and caching does not work
status=200 headers={Cache-Control=[private, max-age=1, public],

Is this because of spring security? Do I need to explicitly set the cache via
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePublic())
                .header("Test", tag)
                .body(Responses);

Why is this happening I couldnt find any documentation?
This is the closest thing ive seen
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/headers.html#headers-cache-control
